# open document after saving properties

Tags: edit-form

i'm developping a webpart in grid format for search results.
On my row document, i've an spfieldmanu and a link to edit properties.
i open the form in a new tab
http:/sp/doclib/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=18

till here everything works well but when i save the document.
it opens the related document (the properties are correctly saved if i look in the document library)
My issue is how to prevent this oppening of document.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I just met with the same problem. For those who stumble upon this thread in the future, the solution is this:
Add `&Source=[some URL]` at the end of the query string. For example:
`http://sp/doclib/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=18&Source=http://sp/doclib/Forms/AllItems.aspx`
or
`http://sp/doclib/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=18&Source=http://sp/doclib/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=18`

The problem is that SharePoint does not know what URL to open after the form is saved. Adding Source parameter to the Query string, passes this information to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding IsDlg=1 to your url

```
   http:/sp/doclib/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=18&IsDlg=1
```

The file will not be downloaded.